# Jquery: can't get ID of div

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm having a very basic problem.  My code isn't working because it isn't recognizing the div that's calling the jQuery.

I try to alert it with `this.id` or `$(this).attr('id')` and I get no alerts when clicking on the divs in question.  But I do get alerts when I click on other elements.  Here is my HTML:

```
 <div id="map"><img src="../../images/map2.jpg" /></div>
    <div id="n_america" style="position:absolute;top:171px;"><img src="../../images/maps/north_america.jpg" /></div>
    <div id="euro" style="position:absolute;top:171px;"><img src="../../images/maps/eurafrica.jpg" /></div>
<div id="table-bottom" style="position:absolute; margin-top:-70px;">
    <div id="table-btm-title" style="width:255px;"><a id="north_america" href="#">North America and Latin America</a></div>
    <div id="table-btm-title" style="width:147px;"><a id="eurafrica" href="#">Europe and Africa</a></div>
    <div id="table-btm-title" style="width:230px; border:none;"><a id="asiapacific" href="#">Asia and South Pacific</a></div>
</div>
```

and here is my jQuery:

```
$(function(){
 $('#n_america').css({ opacity: 0 });
 $('#euro').css({ opacity: 0 });
 $('#north_america').click(function() {
    $('#map').animate({ opacity: 0}, 'slow');
   $('#n_america').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 'slow');
  $('#euro').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 'slow');
  $('#n_america').imagemap([
  /...
  ]);
    });

 $('#eurafrica').click(function() {
    $('#map').animate({ opacity: 0}, 'slow');
   $('#euro').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 'slow');
  $('#n_america').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 'slow');
  if (this.id == 'euro') {
   $('#euro').imagemap([
    /...
   ]);
  }

 });

});
```

The image map plug in works fine for Europe but not for North America.  North America was working yesterday until I added Europe.  But commenting out the Europe image map doesn't "reactivate" the North America code.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you narrow down your example a little?

Firstly, there's no element in your HTML with the id `eurafrica`, so it's hard to see how the `click` event is being fired.

Comment: You have included a lot of irrelevant code. Please pare it down to just the code that actually is needed to reproduce the problem. (Animating the opacity of the elements, for example, is unrelated, right?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#eurafrica').click(function() {
  //...
  if (this.id == 'euro') {
    // This will never be true
```

You are assigning a click handler to an element with id `eurafrica`; of course the element passed in will never have an id of `euro`.

If `eurafrica` (which you do not include in your code) is a parent element of all these elements, you could either do:

```
$('#map, #n_america, #euro').click(function(){
  if (this.id=='euro'){ ... }
});
```

Or:

```
$('#eurafrica').click(function(e){
  if (e.target.id=='euro'){ ... }
});
```

Comment: I'll try this.  It sounds promising.

Comment: Do or do not. There is no _try_. :)

Answer (score 0):

why do you even need the variable ID-check if you click on the element with the fixed id "eurafrica"?

Comment: I'm just trying to alert various elements to determine why the code is not being executed properly.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
$(this).attr('id').getValue();
```

Comment: this.id is so much shorter! What is this .getValue() all about?

Comment: a jquery object doesn't even have a method getValue